Problem with tidyquant using Alpha Vantage
After setting my Alpha Vantage API, I'm trying to run
  library(tidyverse)
  library(tidyquant)
# av_api_key( YOUR ALPHA VANTAGE API KEY)
  earn <- tq_get( c("MSFT", "AAPL"), get = "alphavantage", av_fun = "EARNINGS",outputsize = "full")

and get no output with the warning message
  ℹ There were 2 warnings in `dplyr::mutate()`.
  The first warning was:
  ℹ In argument: `data.. = purr::map(...)`.
  Caused by warning:
  ! x = 'MSFT', get = 'alphavantager': Error in if (content_list[1] %>% names() == "Meta Data") {: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
  Removing MSFT.

Change MSFT to something else doesn't solve the problem.
Is there a problem with using tidyquant to retrieve data from Alpha Vantage?
The desired behavior is that I would like tq_get() to return the earnings.  I have included the error message.

Possibly only a side note. According to https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tidyquant/versions/1.0.9/topics/tq_get it's get = "alphavantager".

If look on the help page for tq_get, you'll see that the examples for Alpha Vangage have it with and without the trailing r.  I've tried it both ways and get the same warning message and failure to get results.  Thanks for thinking about it.

You are more likely to receive an answer if you make your question reproducible.

OK, I've added the calls to the two required libraries.  Anyone trying to recreate this will need their own Alpha Vantage API key

To whoever closed this question, please tell me which of the three elements of the three necessary elements of a question this post lacks.

@WaltS If you want some help with improving your question, ask on [meta].
